# Using script to remotely execute whiptail script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote-access, whiptail

I am trying to execute a bash script that contains whiptail remotely through ssh. The problem is that ssh won't show any of the whiptail UI.

What would be the best way to display the whiptail prompts on a local computer?

The script is an interactive script on a remote server that needs to be triggered (and the prompts need to be answered by a user) through a script on a the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail) the Whiptail you're talking about?

To interact with a Text-based UI (TUI), you need to run ssh with the `-t` flag like this

```
ssh -t user@host.name 'whiptail --title "Example Dialog" --msgbox "This is an example of a message box. You must hit OK to continue." 8 78'
```

The above command is tested to work. Take note that you have to put the entire command in quotes esp. if it has flags.